My controller don't validate my Java Model
I'm trying to validate my Model, which I annotated with:
@NotEmpty(message="name cannot be null")
@Size(min=1, max=32)
@Column(name="artist_name")

for example, however when I send a request in Insomnia, it does not validate and returns a 200 OK (meaning the request was successful). The biggest issue is that even when a field is null, it manages to send the request, and the other issue related to size, because even with a max of 40 in some fields, it exceeds and sends the request anyway.
Post Method:
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Quadro> createQuadro(@Valid @ModelAttribute Quadro quadroMap, BindingResult result,
            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println(result);
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return new ResponseEntity<Quadro>(quadroMap, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
        String fileType;
        if (file.getContentType().equals("image/jpg")) {
            fileType = ".jpg";
        } else if (file.getContentType().equals("image/jpeg")) {
            fileType = ".jpeg";     
        } else if (file.getContentType().equals("image/png")) {
            fileType = ".png";
        } else {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Unsupported file type. Only JPG or PNG files are allowed.");
        }

        Quadro quadro = quadroMap;
        
        String uniqueIdentifier = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        String dataWithUniqueId = file.getOriginalFilename() + uniqueIdentifier;

        String imagemfinal = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(dataWithUniqueId) + fileType;

        
        quadro.setImagem(imagemfinal);
        
       
        storageService.store(file,imagemfinal);
        
        
        quadroService.createQuadro(quadro);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Quadro>(quadroMap, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

Model:
@Valid
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Valid
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message ="o nome não pode ser null")
    @Size(min=1, max=32)
    @Column(name = "nome_artista")
    private String nomeArtista;

    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message ="o nome não pode ser null")
    @Size(min=1, max=40)
    @Column(name = "nome_album")
    private String nomeAlbum;

    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message ="o ano não pode ser null")
    @Size(min=4, max=4)
    @Column(name = "ano")
    private int ano;

    @NotEmpty(message ="o genero não pode ser null")
    @Size(min=3, max=20)
    @Column(name = "genero")
    private String genero;

    @NotEmpty(message ="a duracao não pode ser null")
    @Size(max=3)
    @Column(name = "duracao")
    private int duracao;

Request Ok:

I already tried to insert the ModelAttribute as quadroMAp and others, i dunno why this is happening

Avoid taking screenshots of code and uploading them here. Just copy-paste the content directly into the question Markdown editor.

Do you have validator in your pom? Hibernate validator is common.

Thank You Ilya, the problem already solved, my pom dependencies were the problem.
(i'm using the hibernator as you said)
